# Screen capturing on Android devices with the further postprocessing using TensorFlow lite

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, screen-capture

I'd like to use TensorFlow Lite model on Android devices for object detection.

Could you please advice the best way how to capture the screen with the further overlaying the screen "on fly" - drawing boxes over the found objects or whatever?

UPD: I meant objects like an cat, dog or car in a video stream displaying on the screen. The idea is to highlight the identified objects in the real-time "on fly".

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by 'objects'  since they could be screen widgets such as buttons, text boxes, etc. or objects like 'apple' or 'car' as viewed from a camera or static image.

Comment: I meant objects like an cat, dog or car in a video stream displaying on the screen. The idea is to highlight the identified objects in the real-time "on fly".

Comment: Reminder that StackOverflow does [expect some research effort on your part](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/295004) since the [Tensorflow Lite Tutorials page](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials) has an [example object detection Android app with github hosted source code](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview) and if you have, a better question would be to show code and error logs of where you are having difficulty.

Comment: Hi @MorrisonChang, thank you for clarification, I've looked into the example, the point that it's a dedicated application utilizing camera. My question is mostly about how to run the object detection in the background like a "resident" program.
I.e. I need to capture the screen while another app is running, try to detect an object and highlight it by overlaying - drawing boxes over the screen in the real-time.

Comment: If you are trying to identify "a cat, dog or car" that should be done in a dedicated app as physical camera access is restricted to the foreground app for security reasons. Any app that can capture the screen from the background OR draw over the current screen also has security implications and is distinct from using Tensorflow Lite and should be different questions.